# Dataframe - Merge columns from csv and excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Hi there stack overflow community,

I have the following dataframe in an excel:

```
sparte  sparten      status stati       gesellschaft    gesellschaften
10      Krankenvoll     B   beantragt       0          - Allgemein -
11      Reisekranken    A   aktiv         10000        nordinvest
12      Krankenkasse    N   beitragsfrei  M552D        SV SparkassenVersicherung
```

and the folliwing column for merging in a csv:

```
   sparten    status    gesellschaft
    10           B          0
    11           A        10000
    12           N        M552D
```

to merge some columns from an excel and a csv file I'm using the following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'path', sep=',').drop(columns = ['risiko'])
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'path')

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2[['status','stati']],on='status', how='left').drop(columns = ['status'])
df4 = df3.merge(df2[['sparte','sparten']],on='sparte', how='left').drop(columns = ['sparte'])
```

It works fine for me, but now i want to me merge the following column:

```
    df4 = df3.merge(df2[['gesellschaft','gesellschaften']],on='gesellschaft', how='left')
    print(df4)
```

...and it does not work. It merges only the cells with this format `M552D`, but leaves the cells with numbers untouched. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I try to put `how='right'` the merge works, but the other columns disappear.

Maybe someone has an idea what is happening here! Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing an extract of data to have a [mre]... But if you find some values with `how='right'` and some others with `how='left'` you could try `how='outer'` to keep all the values

Comment: But I've posted a minimal reproducible example above. I've edited it to provide an example of the data in the csv.  how='outer' doesn't work for me in this case :/

Comment: The data was missing. I can now understand what the problem is and why `outer` has no effect: Excel makes a difference between numeric and text values (`1.0` is not the same as `"1.0"`), while this difference cannot exist in a csv file. And Pandas gives the same type to a full column. But I have to make some tests before being able to post an answer

Comment: I undertsand. Thanks for the hint. I'll try to fix it, if you've any solution for me, let me know.

Comment: I've tried to convert the excel into csv, but i got error KeyError: "None of [Index(['status', 'stati'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: I found a solution :) I've converted the excel into csv    `df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mallk\OneDrive\Desktop\Koenigswege\P-Controlling\Datenbank\Daily_Up\metadaten\king\metadaten__du.csv', sep=';')`, this worked for me, but anyway let me know if you found a solution to merge csv with excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `geselschaft` column contains only strings in `df1` which is loaded with `read_csv`, because the column is not fully numeric. But in `df2` which is loaded with `read_excel`, it contains a mix of int and string values. And at Pandas level and int and a string cannot be equal.

A possible workaround is to force a string conversion at merge time:

```
df4 = df3.merge(df2[['gesellschaft','gesellschaften']], left_on='gesellschaft',
  right_on = df2['gesellschaft'].astype('str'), how='left')
```